# Aligns the icons left materialize?

Tags: html, css, material-design, materialize

Look at this two images, and please tell me what is going on?

Why the icons moving ?

[Image 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DIKX9.jpg)

[Image 02](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3nFue.jpg)

i'm stuck on this for about an hour...

The icons must be align on the right or left, the 3 icons are "floating left" but still look like this...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">


    <!--Import Google Icon Font-->
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
    <!--Import materialize.css-->
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/materialize.min.css"  media="screen,projection"/>
    <!--Let browser know website is optimized for mobile-->
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>



    <title>Duall Sistemas</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/materialize.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/custom.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/bootstrap/bootstrap-social.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css">
    <base href="/index.ejs">
    
  </head>

  <body>

<div class="navbar-fixed">
  <nav>
    <div class="row">  
      <div class="col s12 ">
        <div class="nav-wrapper">
      


      <a href="/home" class="brand-logo">Duall Sistemas</a>
      <a href="#" data-activates="mobile-demo" class="button-collapse right"><i class="material-icons">menu</i></a>
      <ul class="right hide-on-med-and-down">
        <li><a href="/home">Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact">Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about">Sobre</a></li>
      </ul>

      <!-- Menu para Mobile -->
      <ul class="side-nav" id="mobile-demo">
        <li>
          <div class="userView">
            <img class="background" src="img/image03.jpg">
              <a href="#!user"><img class="circle" src="img/duallsistemas.png"></a>
              <a href="/home"><span class="white-text name">Duall Sistemas</span></a>
              <a href="#!email"><span class="white-text email">duallsistemas@gmail.com</span></a>
          </div>
        </li>
    
    
        <li><a href="/home"><i class="material-icons">home</i>Principal</a></li>
        <li><a href="/contact"><i class="material-icons">mail</i>Contato</a></li>
        <li><a href="/about"><i class="material-icons">favorite border</i>Sobre</a></li>
      </ul>
      

    







      <script>
          $(document).ready(function(){

            $(".button-collapse").sideNav({
                closeOnClick: true
            });  

          })
      </script>
          
        </div>      
      </div>  
    </div>
  </nav>
</div>


    
<!-- DIV que recebe as VIEWs na pasta Partials de acordo com os Controlleres -->
      <div class="container" id="container-main">
       <div ng-view>
          
        </div>
      </div>



<!-- Scripts para inicializar o Angular e seus Controladores -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/materialize.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-resource/angular-resource.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="libs/angular-bootstrap/ui-bootstrap-tpls.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/navController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/aboutController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/controllers/contactController.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/services/Api.js"></script>


  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Looks like a float issue, what does the CSS look like?

Comment: Open the pictures @Paulie_D plz.

Comment: It's materialize CSS bro, like bootstrap @CarlCasbolt

Comment: We don't want *pictures* of code, we want a [mcve]

Comment: Just for you bro, edit, now, solve it, if you can. :)

Comment: Noooo! A proper [mcve] that **actually demonstrates** the issue.

Comment: Showing what CSS you are using would help.

Comment: Bro the css is the Materialize.css, i just can't show it here, has at least 50000 lines

Comment: One more edit honey, can you help? or just here for fun?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are floating your icons to the left and the following elements are catching on it.

Try setting clear left on your lis.

```
li {clear: left;}
```

Comment: always the simple stuff, love you bro <3